# With Nokogiri, how can I close unmatched tags?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am scraping HTML documents with Nokogiri, many of which may have unclosed tags. I'd like to close "unclosed" `<p>` tags, for example.

I've looked through the docs and see where ["Nokogiri corrects bad-markup,"](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/ensuring_well_formed_markup.html) but I don't see a good way to do this.

Maybe it requires looping through each element and closing any unmatched tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nokogiri fixes them automatically.

You can use `inner_html` to get the corrected HTML code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<p>')
doc.inner_html # => "<html><body><p></p></body></html>"
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do anything special for Nokogiri to close unclosed tags. Check this out:

```
1.9.3p327 :001 > require 'nokogiri'
 => true 
1.9.3p327 :002 > doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse('<a><b></b>')
 => #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0xee4a80 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0xee4710 name="a" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0xee4508 name="b">]>]>
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, I do see using that shows me lots of errors regarding the unclosed tags, but doesn't seem to return the corrected body, which is what I'm after.